# Как перенаправить консоли в TextBox в C#

Tags: c#, консоль, textbox

Здравствуйте!!!
Вот что я хочу сделать. у меня есть две buttons и два textbox, и сначала я хочу что-то написать в textbox1, и это сообщение перенаправлено в консоль, и в это время, когда появилось что-то новое в моей консоли, textbox2 должно прочитать его, и процесс должен продолжаться и продолжаться Я хочу использовать мою простую библиотеку dll, которая работает в этом сценарии. Я знаю, как писать сообщения в консоль, но не могу читать каждый новый с консоли и писать его textbox2. Можете ли вы, ребята, помочь мне?

Comment: Что за консоль имеется ввиду?

Comment: покажите код, который из  textbox1 пишет в консоль